# Как изменить количество элементов в owl carousel для мобильных?

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

Никак не могу разобраться как изменить количество выводимых элементов в `owl carousel` для мобильных? Сейчас скрипт такой. Вывожу 5 элементов. На десктопе хорошо выглядит, но на мобильном становятся слишком мелкими.
 Как правильно написать медиазапрос в скрипте, чтобы поменять количество выводимых элментов? Нужны ли дополнительные правила в `CSS`?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

items:5,
margin:10,
loop:true,
autoplay:true,
autoplayTimeout:2000

 });

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
<script>
 function carouselFn(){
 if ($(window).width() < 500){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

     items:1,
     margin:10,
     loop:true,
     autoplay:true,
     autoplayTimeout:2000
     });
  }
  else{
   $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

    items:5,
    margin:10,
    loop:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2000
   });
  }
 };

 $(document).ready(function() {
     carouselFn();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
     carouselFn();     
 });
</script>
```

А ещё взять и записать это в `function` и уже вызывать, как при **document.ready**, так и потом при **window.resize**

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш вариант сработал! Поясните пожалуйста только вот эту ремарку "А ещо взять в записать это в function и уже вызывать как при document.ready так и потом при window.resize". Я увы пока не сильна в JS и не все могу понять

Comment: изменил. Теперь код будет срабатывать даже при изменение положение екрана.

Answer (score 2):

у меня стоит так (slidesToShow - сколько слайдов должно отображаться, slidesToScroll - сколько скролиться за один скрол):

```
{
  breakpoint: 640,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    arrows: true
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 377,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        // от 0 и больше
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        // от 600 и больше
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        // от 1000 и больше
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
})
```

Ответы выше не совсем правильные, смотрите внимательней мануал к owl-carousel там есть адаптивность "[responsive](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html)".

Пользуйтесь ей.

Comment: спасибо большое! Была не внимательна, не увидела этого в мануале, когда читала